# Why does the $\sigma$-algebra generated by a random variable contain $\emptyset$, and $\Omega$?

Tags: measure-theory, random-variables, set-theory

I was wondering about the definition of the $\sigma$-algebra generated by a random variable (taken from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigma-algebra#.CF.83-algebra_generated_by_random_variable_or_vector)):

$$
\sigma(X) = \{X^{-1}(A) :A\in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n) \}
$$
Which in 'normal speak' to me says: ok, we need all subsets of the preimage of A that are measureable.

Now let's say I have $X_1$ defined as follows:
$$
X_1 = 
 \begin{cases}
1 & \text{if } \omega \in \{uu,ud\} \\
-1 & \text{if } \omega \in \{du,dd\} \\
\end{cases}
$$
With $\Omega  = \{ u,d,uu,ud,du,dd\}$. My reasoning would be that the $\sigma$-algebra of $X_1$ would be:
$$
\mathcal{F}_1 = \{\{uu,ud\},\{du,dd\}\}
$$
my question is: why the inclusion of $\{\emptyset, \Omega\}$? I do understand why that is included for a 'normal' $\sigma$-algebra on a sample space. What is the difference? Any hints/tips would be appreciated.

Comment: Your "definition" of $X_1$ is incomplete. What values does it take if $\omega\in\{u,d\}$?

Comment: @drhab that would why i was confused, love my teachers notes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We know that $\emptyset, \mathbb R^n \in \mathcal B(\mathbb R^n)$, therefore
$X^{-1}(\emptyset), X^{-1}(\mathbb R^n) \in \sigma(X)$.

What elements does a function map to the empty-set?
There's no such element, because if there were, that'd imply there's an $(a,f(a)) \in \operatorname{graph}(f)$, such that $f(a) \in \emptyset$. This is absurd.

So $\emptyset$ is the preimage of $\emptyset$ (which is in every $\sigma$-algebra), therefore it's in $\sigma(X)$.

What elements does a function map into its range?
By definition, every element in its domain, so $\sigma(X) \ni X^{-1}(\mathbb R^n) = \Omega$

Comment: I guess in this case $\mathbb{R^n} = \Omega$. Let me go through what you said..

Comment: so i've got a question, you first say that no element element does a function map to the empty set but you then go on to say the inverse image of $\emptyset$ is $\emptyset$ that seems contradictory... But I also understand that it holds,, is that moreover because of the definition of an empty set?

Comment: My problem with the second part was that I was looking at the range as the only possibilities, why does the definition not interfere with saying $\Omega = X^{-1}(\mathbb(R^n)$? As $\mathbb{R^n}$ is not explicitely stated in the definition of $X_1$

Comment: @WiseStrawberry The inverse image of a set $A$ by a function is simply the set of elements that the function maps into $A$. If there are no such elements, then the inverse image will be the set with no elements, i.e. the $\emptyset$.

Comment: Lol. Thanks for that. Back to calculus I i go. haha Yeah that sounds reasonable. And the thing about $\mathbb{R^n}$?

Comment: @WiseStrawberry The point is that if the function $f$ maps into the set $S$, then the answer to the question "What elements does the function map into $S$?" is simply the "set of elements that the function is defined on". As far as I know, $X$ should be defined on the whole $\Omega$.

Comment: @WiseStrawberry By the way, $\sigma(X)$ is a $\sigma$-algebra! :) Can you prove that?

Comment: you're absolutely right, i considerd  \{\{uu,ud\},\{du,dd\}\} to be two seperate cases, but of course those are 4 inputs. It is defined for the entirety of $\Omega$... let me check on your other question

Comment: as far as your other question is concerned, it _IS_ the collection of all possible subsets as we are concerned with unions.. i'd go that route in proving that.

I learned something. Thanks.

Comment: @WiseStrawberry sure thing. The whole proof depends essentially on that the taking-preimage-by-a-function-operator behaves nicely. It keeps intersections, and unions.